# Supported server versions for Oracle 12c client

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle12c

I am not able to find any information on if an Oracle 12c client is going to be able to connect to a Oracle 10.1.0.5 server installation (on a diffrent machine). Both in a Windows enviroment.

Does anyone have information on this?

Comment: IIRC I was able to connect to a 10g oracle (AIX) with 11g client (win).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [mentioned in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17642/intro.htm#i1014187), note 207303.1 on the Oracle Support site has an interoperability matrix between client and server versions. That says that the 12c client is not supported with a 10.1 server, and indeed that connections will error. (You'll need to look at the note for details as information from MOS shouldn't be shared; I think this is generic enough to get away with...).

Even for supported versions, you'll need to test that everything you do does work - supported doesn't necessarily mean there are no known issues, but should mean that anything you find can be investigated and fixed (or worked around) by Oracle Support.

Answer (score 0):

You maay use the sqlnet.ora parameter SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT . Please see " https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF2010 "

Comment: Please do not use links as answers and rather copy and paste the answer here as these links can get broken.